# Why don't we add an "s" suffix to short types?

Tags: java

Why don't we write `s` with short data type like `short s = 2s;` as we write with float e.g `float f = 1.23f`?

I know when we write `float` by default the compiler treats it as `double` and assigns 8 temporary bytes to it, and when it tries to copy that 8 byte to `float`'s 4 that results in a type error, so that is why we write `f` after initializing a `float`, but why we don't do something similar with `short` as by default `int` is a literal type?

Answer (score 7):

The Java Language Specification allows a type suffix of `L` or `l` for long literals. However, it does not provide a type suffix for short values. It's not necessary because:

- Any value that could be represented by a short can also by represented by the default integral type `int`.
- Assignments of an int value to a short variable are allowed if the *value* is a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), whose value can be represented by a short. See the [Java Language Specification, "Assignment Contexts"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Comment: Thomus sir then also any value that could be represented by a float can also be represented by the default type double?.

Comment: It may be necessary, because the inferred type of an integer literal is `int`. Thus, passing the integer literal `3` as a `short` to a generic method or constructor would require an explicit cast (`(short)3`), rather than simply `3s`.

Comment: Exactly as @Sapphire_Brick mentions, It is completely not true that the suffix for short is not necessary. It is very necessary, because when we use short as type in arguments, we cannot pass int literals to it without explicit cast. With so many casts, the code readability goes down. Same goes for the requirement of casting short + short again to short. That is also a wrong design choice, once you are trying to optimize your data structures to not consume too much memory, when you do not need integers above 32767,you end up having such an ugly code and so much work that you want to dump java.

Answer (score 2):

> Why don't we add an “s” suffix to short types?

Because the Java language is inconsistent on this point.

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) is more flexible for no floating numeric primitive types as for floating numeric primitive types :

> **In addition**, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   **type byte, short, char, or int**:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.

I think that  doing a distinction between `byte, short, char, or int` and `float and double` in the way to declare and manipulate them was not really required. It creates inconsistency and so potential mistakes in the use of them.

if  `short s = 10;` is valid because the narrowing primitive conversion is validated by the compiler that it has no lost information,  so `float f = 10.0;` would also have been valid for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

That is because coming from double to a float is truncating value and losing data so the compiler doesn't do that automatically, you have to explicitly tell it. But when going from a smaller size, short, to a larger size, int, it is done automatically as the compiler just has to pad the data and there is no potential loss of data, as opposed to the former case.

Comment: we are also coming from int to short as by default int literal is the standard i think

Comment: However, a short variable can be assigned to an int literal.  For example, `short s = 32767`. This goes from a type of larger size to a type of smaller size. The compiler seems to be looking at the actual value of the right-hand-side int, because `short t = 32768` is not accepted.

Comment: @AndyThomas ah, didn't see it in the app.